# app state does not persist across pages

Tags: reactjs, redux

I mount my app in index.js:

```
const store = configureStore();

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In my first page I disptach my action:

```
  submitForm(e) {
    const language = e.target.value;

    this.props.dispatch(addLanguage(language, 'language', '2'));

    this.props.router.push('2');
  }
```

The action fires:

```
export const addLanguage = (value, language, page) => {
    return {
        type: types.ADD_LANGUAGE,
        value,
        field: language,
        page,
    };
};
```

and it returns the state in my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  id: 0,
  language: '',
  session: '',
  values: '',
  accessCode: '',
  age: 0,
  gender: '',
  ethnicity: '',
  drinkOften: '',
  drinkConcern: '',
};

export default function UserDetails(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_LANGUAGE:
          return {
            ...state,
            [action.field]: action.value,
          };
```

However, when I redirect to page2 in my `submitForm()` the state is still the default state, does anyone know why its not updating? The language property should of updated. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on submit you have redirect with get parameters you need to prevent submit form before run your other submit code:

```
submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const language = e.target.value;

  this.props.dispatch(addLanguage(language, 'language', '2'));

  this.props.router.push('2');
}
```

Comment: @Bomber U can stop the default action by adding e.preventDefault();

Comment: @Bomber replace my submitForm code with yours and try to submit